# Ceiling Operation Gives Wrong answer

Tags: casting, rounding, ceil

`when I Run the following code it gives me answer as 16777216 but it is supposed to give 16777215 why is this so..

```
    int d=33554431;
    d=d-ceil(d/(float)2);
    cout<<d<<" ";
```

Comment: The ceil() function in C++ returns the smallest possible integer value which is greater than or equal to the given argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, at first I misunderstood your question; the title sounds like you are asking why the Ceiling (ceil function) isn't correct.

```
int d=33554431;
d=d-ceil(d/(float)2);
cout<<d<<" ";
```

In your second line, you cast the literal 2 to a float value so the compiler also converts d to a float when it calculates d/2.   Because of the internal representation, float (single precision floating point) are limited in the values that they can accurately represent.  I typically assume no more than 7 digits of precision, if I need more than that, I use doubles.  Anyway if you look at this link (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) integers in the range [16777217,33554432] round to a multiple of 2.  SO when the compiler converts d to a float it becomes 33554432.  You can see that be running the following code:

```
int d1 = 33554431;
float f = d1;
int d2 = f;

cout << d1 << endl;
cout << f << endl;
cout << d2 << endl;
```

To fix your original code, try this:

```
int d=33554431;
d=d-ceil(d/(double)2);
cout<<d<<" ";
```

or

```
int d=33554431;
d=d-ceil(d/2.0);
cout<<d<<" ";
```

Comment: it is giving d as 16777216

Comment: OK, I misunderstood, changed my answer to explain what you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, my calculator says that *33,554,431 / 2* is actually *16,777,215.5*, which means that *ceil(16,777,215.5) = 16,777,216* is actually correct.

Ceil rounds up to the next bigger integer, if that was unclear.

Comment: then it should give output of d as 16777215 but it is giving 16777216